# how to do a function must return User.ID instead of the User.Name

Tags: user, id

How to do a function must return User.ID instead the User.Name?

Is below function right?

```
private int ControlID(SPWeb web, string fieldValue)
{
    if (fieldValue != null)
         return new SPFieldUserValue(web, fieldValue).User.ID;
    else
         return -1;
}
```